# Forth: free video tutorials?

Tags: video, forth

Can you recommend any free [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language)) video tutorials (except for following)?

The only one I know of is Samuel A. Falvo's excellent
"[Over The Shoulder Episode 1: Text Preprocessing in Forth](http://www.falvotech.com/content/videos/ots-01.mpg)".
MPEG. 102 MB.

There are also [videos from the annual Forth Day](http://www.forth.org/svfig/videos/), but I
don't consider those to be tutorials.

(Unfortunately Forth is, like R, C, C++, Java, C#, D, COM,
.NET, F# and Frontier, an unspecific search term. Search tip for Forth: qualify it with "ans" - as in [ANS Forth](ftp://ftp.uu.net/vendor/minerva/x3j14/j14-94.htm), the [ANSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_National_Standards_Institute) Forth Standard.)

---

Accumulated based on answers and other information:

**Introductions to Forth**

- [Forth](http://rubyconf2008.confreaks.com/videos/forth-small.mp4).
  By Ben Stiglitz. At RubyConf 2008 Orlando Florida, U.S.A.
  13 min 35 secs.
  32 MB.
  MP4.

**Advanced**

- [Over The Shoulder Episode 1: Text Preprocessing in Forth](http://www.falvotech.com/content/videos/ots-01.mpg).
  By Samuel A. Falvo.
  1 h 06 min 25 secs.
  102 MB.
  MPEG.

Comment: Here's one on direct threading in TransForth: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmjo6gesmUk

Answer (score 4):

Best Tech Videos is a user driven social content website dedicated to finding the best educational videos for developers, designers, managers and other people in IT. You can search there for Forth tagged videos and include the ones you cited.
The url is http://www.bestechvideos.com/

Comment: Thanks, that is a very useful tip. I just tried it and there was only one tagged with 'forth': http://www.bestechvideos.com/tag/forth But there may be some that have not been tagged correctly. Also the videos are directly downloadable. No work-arounds are needed as for example with YouTube (they just recently changed the HTML again, probably breaking many downloaders).

Comment: wow, that was really strange. First he says it's just two stacks and a map (what about the heap?). Then at the end he talks about the heap. Also he says that in forth you rarely set memory with "!". Then he does it like 5 times. Seems to me lots of forth programming is messing around directly with memory (with ! and @) and messing with the heap.